# Not able to assign a value from command-line to a property in application.properties file

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot

I have the following settings in my spring-boot project 
`application.properties`:

```
file_path=${lookup_path}
lookup-file.file_1=${file_path}/file1.lku
lookup-file.file_2=${file_path}/file2.lku
```

and a corresponding config class `LookupFileConfiguration`, and also handler class to use this configuration:

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties("lookup-file")
public class LookupFileConfiguration {
    private String file_1;
    private String file_2;
    // getter and setter methods skipped here
}
@Component
public class MyHandler {
    @Autowired
    private LookupFileConfiguration files;
}
```

I tried to run from command line:

```sh
mvn test -Drun.arguments=--lookup_path=C:\\my-proj\target\test-classes\lookupFiles\\
```

But it is not working. `lookup_path` seems not be used in the `application.properties`.

If I hard-code in `application.properties` file

```
file_path=C:\\my-proj\target\test-classes\lookupFiles\\
```

it is working fine.

I know I can use profiles for different environments. However, my project will run test cases in Bamboo plan. So I can only use bamboo variable `${bamboo_build_working_directory}` but cannot predict the directory for test. Please help with a proper solution/suggestion for such case.